# Action bar, navigation drawer with listview

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am novice to android programming and try to implement a `listview` which gets populated from the database. I want to have an `actionbar` with navigation drawer in my application. However as `mainactivity.java` extends `listview`, it's not possible to extend `appcompatibility` class.

I am trying to find solution on internet, but unable to find anything concrete. Is there anyway in which we can implement this? If there is any resource please provide that.

below is code of my `activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

I have one more layout file `app_custom_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/appIcon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>
//android:src="@drawable/facebook" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/appIcon"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/appIcon"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
android:text="Application Title"
android:textSize="22dp"/>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/dlTxt"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/titleTxt"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
android:text="description"
android:textSize="18dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My `main_activity.java` file is below:

```
package com.example.gurje.beyondteaching1;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener{
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initView();

}

private void initView() {
    // show progress dialog
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

    String url = "http://192.168.0.29:8080/connect.php";

    FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
    task.execute(url);
}

@Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // create new adapter
    ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // show failure message
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void NavigationDrawer(){

}
```

}

Now i want to add `actionbar` to it, but as i am already extending `listactivity`, I cant extend `appcompat` which is required to implement `actionbar`

Comment: You describe several different things (NavigationDrawer, Actionbar, AppCompat, Listview).. Its hard to see what you rellay tried until now. Please provide some code so we can help you.

Comment: One option is to make mainactivity.java extends Activity, and then set the layout rootview as a ListView. Once done that, you could change the actionbar.

Comment: Hi please help..i am totally stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Don't extend ListActivity. You can add list to your xml and get it using `findViewById(<id>)`. See example below.

main_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

  }
 }
```